# check if first value of a string is different to the second value java

Tags: java

I have an app which returns the road that somebody is on and I would like to find out whether they are on a different road to the one they started on.

For example, I have

```
userLoc = address.getThoroughfare();
```

which gets their location and stores it, I would like to store that as a string to something like `String firstLoc` and then `if(userLoc.equals(firstLoc))`

Sorry if I was not clear enough, I am asking how to set a String to the first value of `userLoc`, so I may check it against in the future.

Comment: That is how you compare two strings, not sure you need any help. Your code works

Comment: What type is userLoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` instead of equals to save yourself lots of headache down the road.

Basically, to flesh out your code a bit:

```
public boolean isStartingRoad(String loc){
 return loc.equalsIgnoreCase(firstLoc);
}
```

This of course assumes you are saving firstLoc as a global variable in the same class.

And then just call it passing userLoc to it like so

`boolean sameroad = isStartingRoad(address.getThoroughfare());`

Edit: Ok, let me give this another shot:

```
public boolean isStartingRoad(String loc){
     return loc.equalsIgnoreCase(address.getThoroughfare());
    }
```

Basically lets you pass a string for the current location and compares it.

Comment: I'm a little confused, sorry. `firstLoc` has yet to be assigned, I need `(address.getThoroughfare())` to assign firstLoc then assign values to another string after and then check if they are the same

Comment: Works like a charm & exactly what I wanted, thank you very much and thank you for the info with `equalsIgnoreCase`, it will be extremely useful with road names